# Is it advisable to update an old php project from mysql to mysqli?

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) that using the old mysql-functions is not recommended anymore. But is it of any use to make the effort to update the code in an already finshed and running project so only mysqli-functionality is used?

What would be the benefits?
What security issues would be enhanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have you security all right in the current project, it wouldn't be enhanced then.
Though, it is extremely common habit of PHP users to confuse security measures, so, you have to double-check. Say, if you're using a home-brewed version of magic quotes, by escaping all input parameters - you're in danger. 
You need to audit the security despite of changing drivers though.
And you can achieve them without moving to mysqli, though.

As of benefits - there are none, compared to all the pains of rewriting.

If you're still in the mood of rewriting, I have a suggestion:
Instead of just rewriting from one raw API to another, let me suggest you to adopt some database abstraction library, moving raw API calls from all of your code into one compact place.
It will not only make your code dramatically shorter, but also will help in the future, when someone will have a whim to deprecate mysqli in turn - you will have to rewrite your class' methods only, not all the code.

Answer (score 0):

The primary benefits you would gain from upgrading to the PHP mysqli extension are definitively listed on that page:

> The mysqli extension has a number of benefits, the key enhancements over the mysql extension being:
>
> - Object-oriented interface
> - Support for Prepared Statements
> - Support for Multiple Statements
> - Support for Transactions
> - Enhanced debugging capabilities
> - Embedded server support

Security enhancements would generally not be discussed on public forums due to the potential for malicious individuals to use those security concerns on older, unpatched servers. Suffice to say that there are always improvements in new code, especially a driver called the *MySQL* ***improved*** *extension*.

Comment: I am curious, what are enhanced debugging capabilities you are talking about?

Comment: I read those list on that page, and thought, those benefits are all only while you program new stuff. If everything is already done and working, it seems none of those benefits fit to a finished project... that's, why I asked here.

Comment: @rubo77 it is a huge boost to security to be using `prepare` rather than `query` in API calls as it pretty much eliminates possible human error in sanitisation

Comment: Prepare sounds interesting. But then I would not only have to change the database calls in my abstraction layer, but also have to program some more logic to have e benefit from the prepare option?

Comment: @YourCommonSense you probably didn't realize I did a straight cut-n-paste huh?

Comment: @rubo77 if you've _absolutely_ and _definitively_ done _all_ the things that the new library offer, then you are right, you don't need the new lib. However, for new development, you won't have to provide any of that development time, so it will speed you up moving forward.

Comment: And what logic would you need to add on the output of the data layer?